# Saving richtextbox data containg newline, save it to a file and open it using notepad does not show newline in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows form in c#. I have some text in `richtextbox`. I want to save it in text file. In richtextbox, I used both `Environment.NewLine` and `"\r\n"` for newline. If I try to copy `richtextbox` data to a notepad manually, it is working fine. But if I try to save it using 
`File.WriteAllText(path, string.Concat(richtextbox.Text.ToString()));`
or `sw.WriteLine(OutputBox.Text.ToString());` [here sw is for `StreamWriter`] and open it using notepad of windows, it is not showing newlines. But if I try to open it using notepad++, it is working. Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think File.WriteAllText should preserve newlines just right. Try to open the saved file with an hex editor to see what ascii codes are where a '0D 0A' should be...

Comment: I think it converts \r\n to {par} and then upon saving to \n. Some editors are just too dumb to understand \n..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, richTextBox1.Lines);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests using this when you have a richtexbox with multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using TextBox

Set Propertie multiline:

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
```

Save it in text file:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt", true);
writer.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

Using richtextbox

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt", true);

foreach (string l in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    writer.WriteLine(l);
}

writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```